# Error: package directory XYZ does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I have a directory with following structure,

```
.
├── awesome
│   ├── alice
│   │   ├── conf.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── bob
│   │   ├── conf.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── john
│       ├── conf.py
│       └── __init__.py
├── not_awesome_1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── something.py
├── not_awesome_2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── something.py
└── setup.py
```

I want to make the ***`awesome`*** package to be shippable. So, I made the `setup.py` as below,

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="my-awesome-package",
    version="0.1.0",
    description="",
    long_description="",
    license="BSD",
    packages=find_packages(where="awesome"),
    include_package_data=True,
    author="JPG",
    author_email="foo@gmail.com",
    install_requires=[],
)
```

I ran the command ***`python3 setup.py bdist_wheel`*** and it gave me the result

```
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'alice' does not exist
```

---

#### What was I trying to achieve?

I wanted to decouple the `awesome` package and wanted to reuse it in multiple projects as I'm currently using the same in `not_awesome_1` or `not_awesome_2` packages.

In other words, after the successful installation of `my-awesome-package` I should be able to use the `awesome` packge as

```py
from awesome.alice.conf import Alice

alice = Alice()
```

#### What have I tried so far?

- replaced `packages=find_packages(where="awesome"),` with **`packages=find_packages(),`**, but, during the build it also includes the *`not_awesome_X`* packages as well - which is not intended.
- Intriduced **`package_dir`** as well

  ```py
  setup(
      # other options
      packages=find_packages(where="awesome"),
      package_dir={"": "awesome"},
  )
  ```

  But, this doesn't allow me to import my packages as ***`from awesome.alice.conf import Alice`***, but, *`from alice.conf import Alice`* (ie, `awesome` is missing)

#### Questions?

1. What was I doing wrong here?
2. How to properly configure `packages` and `package_dir`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a similar error. Try manually defining both the top-level package and the sub-packages:
`packages=["awesome", "awesome.alice", "awesome.bob", "awesome.john", "awesome.something.somethingelse"]`.

Edit:
The issue is that using the `where` kwarg defines the package to search in. Since you have packages in the root of the project that should not be bundled, you'll likely need to manually add the parent package's name in front of each of its sub-packages.

```
from setuptools import find_packages

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(find_packages(where="awesome"))
    # ['bob', 'alice', 'john', 'john.child']
    # the problem here is that 'awesome' is the root, not the current directory containing awesome

    root_package = "awesome"
    print([root_package] + [f"{root_package}.{item}" for item in find_packages(where=root_package)])
    # ['awesome', 'awesome.bob', 'awesome.alice', 'awesome.john', 'awesome.john.child']
```

Then, in your setup.py:

```
...
root_package = "awesome"
...
setup(
    # other options
    packages=[root_package] + [f"{root_package}.{item}" for item in find_packages(where=root_package)],
    # package_dir={"": "awesome"}, <- not needed
)
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but I am building with ```python3 setup.py sdist```.

Comment: Adding packages manually is not a scalable way to tackle the situation.

Comment: ```find_packages(where="awesome")``` should just return a list, such as the one I manually create. Can you try running that in a file, such as ```test.py``` and provide its output? I'm wondering what ```find_packages(where="awesome")``` is returning.

Comment: Also, ```package directory 'alice' does not exist``` seems to suggest that it simply cannot find the directory... is the terminal that you're running the build command from CD'd into the parent directory?

Comment: @JPG I recreated your directory structure and got it working, check the edit in the original answer.